# Curl resolve equilant in nodejs (fake the hostname of an ip)

Tags: node.js, curl, nginx, https, http-headers

I have an https server running on nginx. Nginx contains two server blocks. Both of them uses different keys and certificates. These are self signed certificates provided by a CA.

Block 1: (Default block)

```
listen 443 ssl;

ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout  5m;

ssl_certificate      /etc/opt/cde/.nginx/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/opt/cde/.nginx/key.pem;
```

Block 2:

```
server_name example.com www.example.com

server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout  5m;

ssl_certificate      /etc/opt/abc/.nginx/certificate.pem;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/opt/abc/.nginx/key.key;
ssl_client_certificate /etc/opt/abc/.nginx/caBundle.pem;
```

Server two has a name abc.com. I want to make an https request to server abc.com. The ip of host machine is something i.e. 10.1.1.36. If I make a http request with hostname=10.1.1.36 , the request goes to the default server in nginx, hence the https certificate validation fails. How can I make a request which will go to the ip but with host name as example.com, so it lands on second server block on nginx?

With curl, this request can be made using --resolve option.

```
curl --cacert cabundle.crt --cert certificate.pem --cert-type PEM --key privatekey.prv --pass passphrase --key-type PEM  --resolve example.com:443:10.1.1.36  https://example.com:443/api/v1/authdata -k GET
```

How can I achieve this using nodejs https request module?

```
var options = {
        hostname: hostname,
        //host: hostname,
        port: 443,
        path: path,
        method: method,
        headers: requestHeaders,
        ca: fs.readFileSync("C:\\cabundle.crt"),
        key: fs.readFileSync("C:\\privatekey.prv"),
        cert: fs.readFileSync("C:\\certificate.pem"),
        passphrase: "passphrase"
    };
    var req = https.request(options, function(res){});
```

Comment: If you need the `hostname` as an IP address, you could try `setHost: false` and add a `Host` header with the value `example.com`.

Comment: @RichardSmith, how to use setHost? Should it be part of options? It didn't work for me.

Comment: IDK, I just saw it as an option in the manual.

Comment: This worked thanks @RichardSmith.