# How to resolve a request in Node js

Tags: node.js, dns

With curl, I can use --resolve: Like so:

```
curl --resolve 'hostname:80:35.247.XX.XXX' "http://hostname/initiatecall?"
```

This is the same as adding the ip address to /etc/hosts.

What is the equivalent to making this request on a node.js server?

How do I resolve a get request with a specific ip address?

Comment: I don't think there is an equivalent like that in NodeJS. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52838122/curl-resolve-equilant-in-nodejs-fake-the-hostname-of-an-ip

Comment: You can check child_process in node to execute curl request directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let response = await axios.get('http://35.247.XX.XXX/someEndpoint', {
        headers: { Host: "hostname.test" }
    });
```

You can make a request to the ip address and simply pass in the hostname through the headers.